# nag: "Warning: Unmatched ``\flushright'' command"

Tags: horizontal-alignment, nag

I'm getting "nag Warning: Unmatched ``\flushright'' command" from nag:

```
\RequirePackage[orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\flushright some text
\end{document}
```

It does not help to group the `flushright`:

```
{\flushright some text}
```

I don't understand what "Unmatched" means in this warning, and I don't understand how nag would like to see `\flushright` used.  What is orthodox?

Comment: flushright is an environment, use \raggedleft.

Comment: Thanks, that works. And all this time I thought \raggedright and \flushright were a pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For once `nag` is right.

You should never use `\flushright`, `\center` or `\flushleft` in the document. Their usage should be reserved to defining other environments and in that case there *must* be the corresponding `\end...` instruction in the end part of the environment.

The advice is not specific to the `flushright`, `center` or `flushleft` environments. Anything that's presented as an environment in the LaTeX manual follows the same rule.

The corresponding declarations are

```
\raggedleft  \centering  \raggedright
```

On the other hand, I'm not sure what an application of `\raggedleft` would be in a document without proper grouping. And then it's easier to use

```
\begin{flushright}
...
\end{flushright}
```

that also provides proper spacing before and after.